# Python: SciPy DCT does not work on large matrices

Tags: python, scipy, fft, large-data, dct

I need to compute the DCT of a large matrix. My code seems to work fine for smaller matrices, but throws the following error for a matrix of size 50000 by 50000:

```
error: (n>0&&n<=size(x)) failed for the 1st keyword n: ddct2:n=50000
```

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import fftpack

# this works fine
y = fftpack.dct(np.random.normal(size = (1000,1000)))
# this throws an error
z = fftpack.dct(np.random.normal(size = (50000,50000)))
```

How to solve this? Many thanks.

Comment: I believe the problem lies in memory allocation. It is necessary to allocate memory for a numpy array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work for me using `scipy.fft` (not `fftpack`):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.fft as fft

x = np.random.normal(size=(50000,50000))
y = fft.dct(x)
```

Note, though, that a square ndarray of size 50000 will need upwards of 20 GB. You may run into issues processing that much data in one shot.

Version notes: Python 3.9.2, NumPy 1.19.3, SciPy 1.6.1

Comment: Thank you! In Spyder somehow 'from scipy import fft' doesn't work for me, because it confuses it with the numpy function numpy.fft. So for instance, I would type fft.dct and it would give me 'error: function object does not have attribute 'dct''. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used Spyder. Maybe try `import scipy.fft as scfft` and then call `scfft.dct`?

Comment: Solved it in the end. Really stupid I just had to get the newer version of numpy where they solved this problem. Thanks so much for all the help!